# How complete OTA Software/Firmware Updates?

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I assigned software to a device and I imported the software OTA dashboard and I can see that the software update is initiated and is in the queue. However, it stays in that state. How to complete the software transmission?

Device: Raspberry pi (as a Gateway with tb IoT Gateway installed)
Software: Simple hello world linux shell script

Comment: The documentation in OTA updates does not elaborate much in this part. Appreciate all answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.